# Show that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{xe^{1/x}}$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital

Set
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{xe^{1/x}}.$$
I would like to prove
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$$
using the definition of limits or results directly related.

**What I have tried:** Let $(x_n)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence converging to zero with $x_n\neq 0$ for all $n$. Need to show
$$f(x_n)\to 0.$$
I am not sure where to go from here. I am not currently asking for a full solution, but a good hint (I would still like to do some of it on my own).

Comment: ... except it doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you help me understand why? Also, would anything change if I tried something like $\frac{1}{xe^{1/x^2}}$?

Comment: It would change. The essential is that $\lim_{x\to 0^-} xe^{1/x}=0^-$

Comment: Could you help me understand why? I really do not know where to start.

Comment: First, the limits from the left and right do not agree.  It might be useful to think about each of those separately.  ($\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \mathrm{e}^{1/x} = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \mathrm{e}^{1/x} = 0$ is a good place to start.)

Comment: Ah that makes sense. The left and right hand limit do not agree, but I am not quite seeing how when I multiply by $1/x$ this same fact follows. Informally, I see that $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{xe^{1/x}}=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{1}{xe^{1/x}}=\infty$.

Comment: @northcity4 : The limit from the left is $-\infty$ (because the denominator is negative for such $x$s).

Comment: Also, you are done: You have asked about a two-sided limit and shown that the two one-sided limits do not agree.  That is, you have shown the two-sided limit does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for catching that. Any way to see the limit from the right hand side rigorously?

Comment: In a real analysis course, I'd use the power series for $x \mathrm{e}^{1/x}$ and observe that this diverges to $\infty$ as $x \rightarrow 0^+$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(1/n)=\frac{n}{e^n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty.$

$f(-1/n)=-ne^n \to -\infty$ as $n \to \infty.$

Consequence ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Letting $t=\frac{1}{x}$, we have $f=\frac{1}{x}\,e^{-\frac{1}{x}}=te^{-t}$ and we need to study $t\to\pm\infty$. Consider then the inequality $$0<\frac{f}{2}<e^{-\frac{t}{2}}$$ for positive $t$. If $t$ is negative, consider instead
$$ 
f<t\,.
$$